# How can I get full-sized image on swatch attribute? Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, image, swatches

I added swatch images for my brand. 
[image: Swatch view]

I get swatch data in my template:

```
$swatchData = $block->getSwatchData();
```

Next step - I show image inside my template:

```
$swatchThumbPath = $block->getSwatchPath('swatch_thumb',
                        $swatchData['swatches'][$option]['value']); ?>
<img src="<?=$swatchThumbPath?>" alt="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $label['label'] ?>">
```

But on page I have compressed picture 110x78 pixels:

[image]

How can I get full-sized picture from swatch data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using **`swatch_image`**

```
 $swatchImagePath = $block->getSwatchPath('swatch_image',
                        $swatchData['swatches'][$option]['value']);
```

Comment: I just delete 'swatch_thumb' block, and it works.